# django sql explorer - user based query access

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I have a django sql explorer which is running with 5 queries and 3 users.

- Query1
- Query2
- Query3
- Query4
- Query5

I want to give access of Query1 and Query5 to user1 
and Query4 and Query2 to user2 and likewise.

my default url after somebody logins is url/explorer

based on users permission he should see only those queries but as of now all users can see all queries,

I tried to search stackoverflow and also other places through google but there is no direct answer. Can someone point me to right resource or help me with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with default implementation. You need to download the source code and customize as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for responding Nayan! I am actually trying auth backends and django-guardian.